# Highlight part of the message body of emails in OS X Mail

Tags: osx-lion, apple-mail

In the Mail application from Mac OS X Lion, is it possible to highlight somehow parts of the text of the emails? I want to store some mails and some weeks later, just read the most important parts (already highlighted) of those emails

Comment: You'd need to define a rule for highlighting this text.  Do you know what I mean by a rule?

Comment: I guess you talk about mail filters, but that is not the point, I want to do that every time I want and using the mouse with every message I like

Comment: Can Automator help you?

Comment: Eir, could you provide your comment as answer and elaborate it a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can distinguish messages that have important text you want to read later. You can do this by replying to the message, then saving the message as a draft, so you can come back whenever you want.  (Copy the important text to your reply, then save it as a draft).  When you want to look back at some of these important emails, you'll see the text snippets you think is important.  If you want, I'll add instructions on how to highlight the emails, so you can find them easier.

(Here’s how to save a draft message as draft):

Choose **Save As Draft** from the **File** menu.

Your drafts are stored in the **Drafts** mailbox or the location you choose next to "**Save unsent mail in**" in the Composing pane of **Mail Preferences**.

To reopen a draft, open the mailbox where you store drafts and double-click the message.

Comment: yes, this is a good idea, but it is quite messy for me

Comment: Maybe you should try it for a day or two... It seems much more complicated than it reads (never that great in English class).

All I can ask is that you try it.